# My C# app is locking a file, how I can find where it does it?

Tags: c#, file, file-io, locking

I'm writing code that check files path calculate hash (SHA1) and copy them.
I made sure that I do not lock them like for example using

```
public static string SHA1(string filePath)
    {
        var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        var formatted = string.Empty;
        using (var sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
        {
            byte[] hash = sha1.ComputeHash(fs);
            foreach (byte b in hash)
            {
                formatted += b.ToString("X2");
            }
        }
        return formatted;
    }
```

So how I can, in Visual Studio, find where it does lock the file?

Comment: Can you post some of your non blocking code, please?

Comment: Add a FileShare argument (next after FileAccess) to the FileStream constructor

Comment: You can shorten `new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);` to `File.OpenRead(filePath);`

Comment: OK what about fs.Dispose(); , it worked for me! why?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Can you keep the above syntax as and give a try?

```
using(var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
//Your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: +1: Just to clarify: the `using` block calls `fs`'s `Dispose()` method when it exits the scope, closing the stream and releasing unmanaged resources. Using a `using` block like this means you don't have to manually call `fs.Close()` after you have finished with the stream and it works with all types with an `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: You are right. Because, ideally clean up of unmanaged resources(suppose if the class is going to use unmanaged resources) should already been handled inside the Dispose() method of Type/Class.

Answer (score 4):

There is a little windows soft : process explorer and in this you can find which process has an handle on a file :

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Locking usually happens whenever you create a file stream on a file without later closing that stream. Unless you call `fs.Close();` in your code, your application will keep the file open (and thus locked).

You could wrap this in a `try-finally` block or try the code that Siva Gopal posted.

Answer (score 1):

You assumption that opening the file stream with just `FileAccess.Read` will not lock the file is faulty; the file is locked while it has been opened for a file operation and has not been closed.

A `FileStream` does not close an opened file until the `FileStream` is garbage collected or you explicitly call its `Close` or `Dispose` method. Either insert such an explicit call as soon as you are done with the file you opened, Or wrap the use of the `FileStream` in a `using` statement, which implies the call to `Dispose`, like other answers suggest.